# Запрет перехода по ссылке и выполнение функции

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Есть ссылка:

```
<a href="http://url.zone/">Link!1</a>
```

нужно: запретить переход по ней при клике, а также при клике выполнить некую функцию. Делал так:

```
<a href="http://url.zone/" onclick="return false">Link!1</a>
```

всё работало, как и написано в коде. Добавил нужную функцию:

```
<a href="http://url.zone/" onclick="return false;about();">Link!1</a>
```

переход также не выполнялся, но и функция не выполнялась. Делал  вот так:

```
<a href="http://url.zone/" onclick="about();return false;">Link!1</a>
```

функция выполнилась, переход произошёл.

Задача: запретить переход по ссылке и выполнить функцию. Нужно это мне для того, чтобы для "человека" (браузера), зашедшего на сайт, выполнялся код функции для этой ссылки, а для поисковиков это была обычная ссылка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать так:

```
<a href="http://url.zone/" onclick="function() {about(); return false;}">Link!1</a>"
```

Это если быстро, а вообще лучше пользоваться обработчиками событий - `attachEvent` для IE и `addEventListener` для других браузеров. IE 9 поддерживает `addEventListener`.

**UPD:**

Тогда добавьте:

```
function(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    abort();

    (evt.preventDefault) ? evt.preventDefault() : evt.returnValue = false;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую)

Comment: Всёравно переходит браузер по ссылке. Mozila FireFox 4.0.1

Answer (score 5):

```
onclick='return about();'  
...  
function about()
{
    //somecode
    return false;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://url.zone/" onclick="javascript:about();">Link!1</a>"

function about(e) {
    e.PreventDefault; // Сразу в начале функции
    //...
}
```